# Possible to add a button to the built-in android calendar?

Tags: android, android-calendar

I don't know if this is even possible, but what i want to do is this:
When the user enters the android calendar and opens the "add new event", i want to add an extra button inside the built-in "new event" activity. Is this possible?

If not, is it possible for me to run my own implementation of "add new event" instead of the built-in one?

I am new when it comes to working with android calendars, so i dont really know how to do it, if it is even possible. If it is possible, i would be really gratefull for some basic code-examples :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your first question is NO, you cannot add a button the the calendar app (simply because it is a google proprietary app).
A solution, more clear and secure, is to develop a thirdy-part application that uses the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/), and interface your app with the google's calendar app and it can adds the particular button (with its particular operation).

This is a [sample application](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate).

More info are on [Google Developers Site](https://developers.google.com/google-apps), it is very well documented